# mysql select all rows that have same value from id

Tags: mysql

I have a sql table like this

```
id|server_name|other|data|
__|___________|_____|____
1|server1     |data |data
2|server1     |data |data
3|server2     |data |data
4|server3     |data |data
```

Im trying to find a select statement where I can give it the id and it will return all the rows that have the same server_name as the id I specified.

so I select id=2 and I will get the rows from id 1 and 2.

I tried this but its just returning everything.

```
SELECT * FROM `backups` WHERE EXISTS(SELECT `server_name` FROM `backups` WHERE `id` = 2);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM backups
WHERE server_name = (SELECT server_name
                     FROM backups
                     WHERE id = 2)
```

or

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM backups AS b1
JOIN backups AS b2 ON b1.server_name = b2.server_name
WHERE b2.id = 2
```

Comment: upvoted. I removed my answer as yours is clear. Why not implicits joins? @Barmar

Comment: I think it's just considered cleaner to use `ON` clauses to distinguish joining conditions from other conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Just use `=` to compare each row's `server_name` with the value returned from your subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM backups
WHERE server_name = (
  SELECT server_name
  FROM backups
  WHERE id = 2)
```

You can do it with a join too:

```
SELECT b2.*
FROM backups b1
JOIN backups b2 ON b2.server_name = b1.server_name
WHERE b1.id = 2
```

Either way, an index on `server_name` will help performance.